# Jmeter testing on multiple websites on the same server

Tags: jmeter

I have a working script to login and get to one website on the webserver, what I need is how to get to the other 10 plus servers with Jmeter ***all at once*** to do a nice stress test on the websites and its interfaces. 
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Just for clarity to helpyou have a farm of 10 instances all serving the same content.  Sitting behind a load balancer?  And you want to hit each server under load?

Comment: no, I have 17 sites all serving different data

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use [DNS Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) available since [JMeter 2.12](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html)

DNS Cache Manager allows each JMeter thread to resolve underlying IP address of the request endpoint on its own.

See [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) guide for detailed explanation of background and configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty trivial using the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

Let's assume you are using normal HTTP Request samplers and that these are already set up with a server and path. Let's say it is the server you want to change for each thread. Then you need to:

1. Create a text file with a different server you want to test on each line.
2. Add a CSV Data Config element to the top level.
3. Configure the CSV Data Config to use your text file and set the variable name of *server*.
4. In your samplers change the server name to ${server}.

You can use the same method to change the path and other details.

Comment: Thank you very much very insightful

Comment: @user177073 Please consider upvoting or marking as correct answers that you have found helpful. I see you haven't done this for many of your questions and it may make it harder for you to get help in future.